# jQuery UI Datepicker using words like "tomorrow" in input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the jQuery UI Datepicker for the following scenario.

The user can either click on a date to add it (works), or click on a button inserting a word (e.g. now, works) or write a date (works) or a word (works) and submit the form. On Edit words are supposed to be show (does not work).

For e.g. if the user clicks a button "forever" this word should be shown in the input field.
Currently I have the correct value in the value field of the input, but I can only manage to show it, using the setDate method, if it is a correct date. (Makes sense).
I also need it to show the words though.

Any Ideas? If possible without editing the original jQuery file, so I don't have trouble updating once they release a new version.

Comment: Could you share your code so far, perhaps create a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sure, but its mostly the default jquery datepicker http://jsfiddle.net/lukasoppermann/R2Err/8/ the styles are missing, but it works so far. I know it uses twice the same ID, but this is just to show that it works with dates, but not with names.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you want to achieve. Do you want that when "Heute" button is clicked, it shows the word "Heute" and the date string in the input?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/william/R2Err/10/

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. What I want is, that in the first input field always is shown. (Always is a word that is set as the value for this field). If I assign it via the setDate, it does not show up of course, because jquery parses it as a date. I hope this is more understandable.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/william/R2Err/11/

Comment: More like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lukasoppermann/R2Err/12/ but yes, awesome. I wonder why it did not work when I did it like this must have messed sth up. Thank you very much. Can you post it as an answer? Otherwise I can not "accept" the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the jsfiddle you provided, it was the `$("#from").datepicker("option","onChangeMonthYear", function( year, month, input ) { ... })` that was playing up. But that seemed to go away when `onChangeMonthYear` is initialised inside `datepicker()`. So, something like the following would help:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, input) {
        ...
    }
}).val('some text');
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/R2Err/11.